# FTP Video Upload and Thumbnail Rotation Issue

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ftp

I am uploading video using ffmpeg command. I am then creating then thumbnail. I want to rotate video, how can I achieve this?

Here is my Code:

```
    $thumbnail_name =  preg_replace('"\.(mp4|avi|flv|vob|oggg)$"', '.jpg', $newfilename);

$movie = "/home/foldername/public_html/master/assets/user_videos/".$newfilename;

$thumbnail = "/home/foldername/public_html/master/assets/user_videos/".$thumbnail_name;

$command = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01 -i '.$movie.' -f image2 -vframes 1 '.$thumbnail.' 2>&1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your command `-vf transpose=1`

Full code: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 0 -vframes 1 -vf transpose=1 out.jpg`

For the transpose parameter you can pass:

```
0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90Clockwise
2 = 90CounterClockwise
3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```

Use -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" for 180 degrees.